# Coldfusion - IIS only one website down

Tags: iis, coldfusion

I have a ColdFusion server with one connector for IIS and multiple websites.
From this morning only one website is down with **Error 500** or **"Service is unavailable"**.
I have checked the web.config and it looks exactly like on the other website and Application Pool identity it's the same for all the pools.

Also I am not able to run any www.mywebsite.com/test.cfm but I am able to run www.mywebsite.com/index.html.

So it's clearly something between of IIS and ColdFusion but the question is that why is not affecting the other websites?
Any advices?

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting **Error** **500**, then please ensure the bitness of both CF and IIS. Else, if you get **Error** **500.19** or any other, please ensure that you have permissions on \ColdFusion11\config\wsconfig.

However if you are getting **"Service is unavailable"**, then either CF Service is not sunning or Application Pool under IIS has crashed. But, since you are able to server html pages, that means either CF service has crashed or not running at all.

You can try to restart CF and that should fix the issue.

Comment: Our ColdFusion 10 websites run fine on IIS, but every once in a while one of them will have a crashed application pool (and be the only website that isn't working).  As a workaround, we monitor each site (using PRTG) and manually restart the site's application pool when it is reported as "offline".  Any idea why this occurs?  It never happened to us before on CF3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 or 9.

Comment: If App pool is crashing, then enable FREB logs to get more details.